# Validate Ajax Combobox using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using ajax combobox in my code in place of dropdownlist and now I want to validate it at
client side. I opt to use javascript and use following code to validate it :

```
function validateCombobox(){
    var comboboxId = document.getElementById('<%=ComboBox1.ClientID%>');
    if(comboboxId.value=="some value") {
        alert("Error");
    }
}
```

But I am unable to validate combobox.

My html code is:

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server"
    AutoCompleteMode="Suggest" 
    CaseSensitive="false" 
    DropDownStyle="DropDownList">
</asp:ComboBox>
```

Code Generated by ASP on browser:

```
<div onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder1$unit\',\'\')', 0)"
    id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_unit" style="display:inline;">
    <table id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_unit_unit_Table"
      class="ajax__combobox_inputcontainer" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"
      style=
      "border-width:0px;border-style:None;border-collapse:collapse;display:inline;position:relative;top:5px;">
        <tr>
            <td class="ajax__combobox_textboxcontainer">
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width:150px;"
                    name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder1$unit$unit_TextBox"                    
                    id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_unit_unit_TextBox" />
            </td>
            <td class="ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer">
                <button type="button" 
                    id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_unit_unit_Button">
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <ul id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_unit_unit_OptionList"
      class="ajax__combobox_itemlist" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;">
        <li>GM</li>
        <li>KG</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="hidden"  value="0" 
        name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder1$unit$unit_HiddenField"\
        id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_unit_unit_HiddenField"/>
</div>
```

Comment: "But I am unable to validate combobox" - Why? Is there an error that you're getting?

Comment: "But I am unable to validate combobox" from this I mean that i am unable to get the value of combobox to match in my if condition.
This helps when I worked with other asp controls like textbox or any other.

Answer (score 2):

Got Solution with the help of answers given by @Sethu and @Scott:

I use following code:

```
function validateCombobox(){
    var comboBox = document.getElementById('<%=ComboBox1.ClientID%>_ComboBox1_TextBox');
    if(comboBox.value=="some value")
    {
        alert("Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The combo box creates multiple html in client side.

Originally the value is stored in a hidden field.

```
function validateCombobox()
{
var comboCotainer= document.getElementById('<%=ComboBox1.ClientID%>');
var hdnField = FindChild(comboCotainer);
if(hdnField != null && hdnField.value == "-1")
{
 alert("Error");
}
}

function FindChild(container) {
        var hiddenControl = null;
        if (container.children && container.children.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < container.children.length; i++) {
                if (container.children[i].type == "hidden") {
                    hiddenControl = container.children[i];
                    break;
                 }
            }
        }

        return hiddenControl;
    }
```

Bit of jquery will eliminate the FindChild function

If you use Jquery then, use the below code

```
function validateCombobox() {
        var selectedVal = $('#<%=ComboBox1.ClientID%> input[type=hidden]').val();
        if (selectedVal == "-1") {
            alert("Error");
        }
    }
```

The hidden control holds the index of selected item, so check for -1 or non-negative value

Comment: You have updated your code to include a static reference `ctl00_ctl00...` that may change.

Comment: @Sethu you are using static refrence and if I change my masterpage then refrence will be changed and we need to do changes at all the scripts. Don't you think its very tedious task.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function validateCombobox(){
    var comboboxObject = document.getElementById('<%=ComboBox1.ClientID%>');
    var inputs = comboboxObject.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'text' && inputs[i].value == "some value") {
            alert("Error");
            break; //why loop further?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx naveen its more simpler solution.